# Replacing Requests with urllib2

Tags: urllib2

I have the following code using `requests` to generate CSRFToken import requests:

```
import requests

class TokenGenerator:
    def GenerateToken(self, uid, pwd):
        TokenGenerator.session = requests.Session()
        TokenGenerator.resp = TokenGenerator.session.get("http://chp1766.neilsoft.in:8000/", cookies={'contact.language': 'en'},auth=(uid,pwd))
        if TokenGenerator.resp.status_code == 200:
            token = TokenGenerator.session.cookies.get('CSRFToken')
            print("TOKEN")
            print(token)


obj = TokenGenerator()
obj.GenerateToken('caddok', '')
```

How can I replace the `requests` module with `urllib2`?

Answer (score 0):

With urllib you can get the same result with the following code:

```
        req1 = urllib2.Request("YOUR URL")
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req1)
        cookie = response.headers.get('CSRFToken')
        print(cookie)
```